# Remotely deleting files in a folder vb.net 2017

Tags: vb.net, networking, lan

I have some code to delete all files within a folder over a LAN network.
I cant figure out why but it never catches the exception to show an error it will just crash i have tested the deleting function offline from the network and that part of the code works fine (Can test over network till back at work tomorrow). Anybody know where im going wrong with this? and also is there a better way to write the code as it feels sloppy like there's too much for the simple function it performs.
Its meant to clear out the time files on 3 temp folders of any files and subfolders of the default temp dir' in windows, first it check a textbox to see if a workstation name has been entered and if not it checks the next textbox for the IP my code is below:

```
 Private Sub TempCleanButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TempCleanButton.Click
    If txtWS.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Deleting Temp Files Please Wait..."
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles("\\" & txtIP.Text & "\C$\Windows\Temp")
            Try

                'Delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
                File.Delete(filePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each SubFolderPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories("\\" & txtIP.Text & "\C$\Windows\Temp")

            ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                Directory.Delete(SubFolderPath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles("\\" & txtIP.Text & "\C$\Windows\Tmp")
            Try

                'Delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
                File.Delete(filePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each SubFolderPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories("\\" & txtIP.Text & "\C$\Windows\Tmp")

            ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                Directory.Delete(SubFolderPath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles("\\" & txtIP.Text & "C:\Users\Environment.UserName\AppData\Local\Temp")
            Try

                'Delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
                File.Delete(filePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each SubFolderPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories("\\" & txtIP.Text & "C:\Users\Environment.UserName\AppData\Local\Temp")

            ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                Directory.Delete(SubFolderPath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try
        Next
    Else
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Deleting Temp Files Please Wait..."
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles("\\" & txtWS.Text & "\C$\Windows\Temp")
            Try

                'Delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
                File.Delete(filePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each SubFolderPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories("\\" & txtWS.Text & "\C$\Windows\Temp")

            ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                Directory.Delete(SubFolderPath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles("\\" & txtWS.Text & "\C$\Windows\Tmp")
            Try

                'Delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
                File.Delete(filePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each SubFolderPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories("\\" & txtWS.Text & "\C$\Windows\Tmp")

            ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                Directory.Delete(SubFolderPath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles("\\" & txtWS.Text & "C:\Users\Environment.UserName\AppData\Local\Temp")
            Try

                'Delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
                File.Delete(filePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each SubFolderPath As String In Directory.GetDirectories("\\" & txtWS.Text & "C:\Users\Environment.UserName\AppData\Local\Temp")

            ' delete the sub-folder if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                Directory.Delete(SubFolderPath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Unable to Delete: " & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This _\\" & txtIP.Text & "C:\Users\Environment.UserName\AppData\Local\Temp_ surely is not a valid path

Comment: well im not able to test over the network until tomorrow but using the Environment.UserName variable it should work so im assuming as it needs to be variable as everyone logs in with their name. why do you think it wont work ?

Comment: Because **A)** Your path will result in for example: `\\1.2.3.4C:\Users\Environment.UserName\AppData\Local\Temp` and **B)** `Environment.UserName` returns the logged in user of **this computer**, but what you have there is a string, so the literal "Environment.UserName" text will always be in the string.

Comment: To do it correctly you gotta add a slash after the IP, change `C:` to `C$`, and finally _**concatenate**_ `Environment.NewLine` instead of literally putting it in the string. -- What it should rather look like: `"\\" & txtIP.Text & "\C$\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Comment: omg of course what a stupid mistake i did it correct with the other paths i cant believe i did not notice that been on making this app all day think i need a break thanks for pointing that out! earlier today it was catching the exception and providing an error message when i file was in use and unable to delete and then i changed some code and now its not working i bet its down to something stupid like the above im going to sleep on it an re look with fresh eyes thanks for your input

Comment: I got all the code working now after having a fresh look today and changing what was advised above! the only issue now is that Environment.Username is pulling the username from my system rather than the remote one how would i change the variable to grab the logged on user from the remote machine ? do i have to use WMI or is there a simpler way ?